# python social auth 404 error

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have create test application with pythn-social-aut in which I login using facebook.

When i click in the facebook link it redirect me to facebook login page. It works correctly

After test app I integrate in application but when i click on the facebok login link it give me 404 error. Even I check step by step but found whats the reason.

I inspect the link its `href=/login/facebook/` is correct but not redirect me to facebook login page

here my code
under my main `urls.py` i have paste

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',


    url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    (r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),


    (r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
    (r'^', include('app.urls')),

    url(r'^(?i)login/$', login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
    url(r'^(?i)logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}),


) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Inside my app.urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^socialcheck/$', 'app.views.socialCheck'),

)
```

100% working in the test app but in main project when i integrate it give 404 error when i click on link

Comment: Show the full code of your `urls.py`, please.

Comment: I have added urls.py i cannot paste all code of urls.py.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very good chance that your problem is in the `urls.py` code which you doesn't show.  I suspect that some of the urls catches the `^/login/([^/]+)/` pattern but doesn't handle the `/login/facebook/` path.

Try to move the social urls to the top of your `urls.py`.  Set it as the first item of the `patterns()`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    ...
)
```

Comment: Issues resolve. just comment the caseinsensitive backends from setting.py. and it work.

Comment: I get the same error. Could you please elaborate what do you mean by " comment the caseinsensitive backends"?